# Why there is no Linux Handbook?

Tags: documentation

Look e.g. onto the BSD's family:

FreeBSD Handbook: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/debugging.html

OpenBSD FAQ, nearby FreeBSD's Handbook: http://www.openbsd.org/faq/index.html

I'm really discouraged what can be called official Linux documentation. Information scattered around the network. Where is the core?

Is it

`ii  linux-doc                                                   3.11.0-14.21                               all          Linux kernel specific documentation for version 3.11.0`

of my Ubuntu?

Comment: Linux is in the first line a kernel. Kernel documentation can be found under `Documentation` in the kernel tree. As of user space, there are many books out there. You can try this one for beginning: http://debian-handbook.info/

Answer (score 3):

Linux isn't a complete OS. The latter is provided with userland part and is often called "distribution". Different distributions have their own documentation which could be more advanced that handbooks you mentioned. Personally for Ubuntu, there is at least on-site documentation.

Comment: That is why I'm ask, where is the **core**? As yegorich noticed, it is `Documentation`. I'm really discouraged with this zombies repeats of one things on every linux's distribution's sites. Open arch, open debian, open ubuntu, open gentoo, you'll find `copy paste` texts of the same things. Looks like core is unexist.

Comment: Why do you think there is a "core"? Linux Documentation/ is just kernel documentation. It doesn't know anything on graphics environment, games, text editors, compiler, etc. And there is no "zombie repeat" if e.g. one distro uses KDE but another is based on XFCE. Either you chasing mirages or simply mistaking the needed docs type. There won't be kernel-only handbook, no need in it. Please determine carefully what you need or explain an exact search request.

Comment: @ConcealmEnt there is no core of a GNU/Linux system. look into what an upstream is. the equivalent in the BSD world is very deemphasized. the fact that there is no GNU/Linux manual is because of a fundamental difference between BSDs and GNU/Linuxes: **BSDs are designed. GNU/Linux is grown.**

Comment: I'm especially point on FreeBSD handbook. Imagine how it would be great to have the same common documentation for Linux, where `XFCE`/`KDE`/`Gnome` would be simple replaced by `X`, everything userland structured into one big sub-topic. Officially, from the dev-team.

Comment: I see your point but can't agree. Linux as kernel isn't sticked e.g. to X, nor X is sticked to Linux. Ubuntu how migrates to Mir instead of X and Wayland is in plans; OTOH there is no X in a WRT based router. So what will be present in such book except local and obsoleted descriptions?

Comment: X is largely unrelated to the window manager or desktop environment, the latter of which is what Xfce/KDE/GNOME/etc provide. If it makes it easier to reason about, think about X as the device driver layer in that it provides a way to access keyboard, mouse, etc. events and a low-level interface to draw things on the display, locally or over a network. X *on its own* is virtually useless; it needs at least a window manager to be marginally useful in practice, and a desktop environment makes using the system far more user friendly. This separation is by design.